# Sticky Header - buggy jumping on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sticky

I have a specific problem on making a sticky header with jQuery. I tried the commonly used snippets around the web, but I perceived the same buggy thing everywhere.

At a specific document height (scrollable until a little more than calling of sticky-effect) the sticky header jumps between `position: fixed` and `position: static`.

**HTML:**

```html
<header>
  <div id="not-sticky"></div>
  <div id="sticky"></div>
</header>
<div id="content"> ...
```

**jQuery:**

```js
var $sticky = $("#sticky");
var offset = $sticky.offset();
var stickyTop = offset.top;
var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (windowTop > stickyTop) {
    $sticky.css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0
    });
  }
  else {
    $sticky.css({
      position: '',
      top: ''
    });
  }
});
```

**CSS:**

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
}

#not-sticky {
  padding: 50px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#sticky {
  padding: 24px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 25;
}
```

I also tried a margin-bottom on `#not-sticky` with the same height as the `#sticky` to keep a constant document-height, but the same jumpy-sticky-effect occurred.

Any idea to fix that thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scroll fires too many times and trying to set an element `style` will always & inevitably create jumps (even barely noticeable but still jaggy).

The best way I've found is to

1. **clone** our element,
2. make that clone `fixed`
3. play with clone's `visibility` style.

**Pure JS:**

```js
;(function(){ /* STICKY */

  var sticky  = document.getElementById("sticky"),
      sticky2 = sticky.cloneNode(true);

  sticky2.style.position = "fixed";
  document.body.appendChild(sticky2);

  function stickIt(){
    sticky2.style.visibility = sticky.getBoundingClientRect().top<0 ? "visible" : "hidden";
  }

  stickIt();
  window.addEventListener("scroll", stickIt, false );
}());
```

```css
#sticky{
  height:100px;
  background:#ada;
  height:50px;
  position:relative;
  /* needed for clone: */
  top:0; 
  width:100%;
}


/* Just for this demo: */
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#content{height:2000px; border:3px dashed #444;}
h1{padding:40px; background:#888;}
```

```html
<h1>Logo</h1>
<div id="sticky">Sticky header</div>
<div id="content">Lorem ipsum...<br>bla bla</div>
```

So when you see the "header" *fix*, that's actually our fixed clone getting visible on-top.

Comment: Thanks man, works great! I hoped it would be possible without a wrapping div to keep a clean markup, but I'll incur that.

Comment: @TimoM you're welcome! I created a reusable function so you can use it also on `DOM ready`, `window load`, wherever you need. You know, images load slowly and might be useful to re-check the scroll value, cause the page could sometimes be already scrolled while visited.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that! I already wrapped the jQuery into the `DOM ready`, but this `sticky()`-function is really neat!

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan How would I set the sticky element to stick x-number of pixels below the top?  Thnx!